# Javascript Basic Math

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I am trying to perform something very basic with JS. I have a countdown which retrieves the ammount of seconds left from a hidden  tag and then parses this. At the end of the function I want it to remove the interval timer from the ammount of seconds in the span tag. At the moment i have done:

```
parseInt($(this).find("#sqbTimestamp").text()) - 3;
```

I then use setTimeout(function,2) to run it every 2 seconds (give it a second leeway to process). However the number outputted from the calculation above into the console log is the same every time it runs through the function.

Here is the full code:

```
function countdownProcedure(){
        var interval = 10000;
        var i = 0;
        var seconds = null;
        console.log(c ++)
        $(".rfqTbl tr").each(function(){
                if(i > 0){
                        seconds = $(this).find("#sqbTimestamp").text();
                        var tsInt = parseInt($(this).find("#sqbTimestamp").text());

                        var days = Math.floor(seconds / (60*60*24));
                        seconds -= days * 60 * 60 * 24;
                        var hours = Math.floor(seconds / (60*60));
                        seconds -= hours * 60 * 60;
                        var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
                        seconds -= minutes * 60;

                        //$(this).find("#sqlTimestamp").text(newTS);
                        console.log(tsInt - 3);

                        if(days < 1){ days=""; }
                        $(this).find("#countDown").html(days + "<pre> Days</pre> " + hours + "<pre>:</pre>" + minutes + "<pre>:</pre>" + seconds);
                        $(this).find("#countDown").append(i + "  -  " + seconds);
                        if(days > 1){
                                $(this).find("#countDown").css({
                                        'color':'#2A7F15',
                                        'font-weight':'bold'
                                });
                        };
                        if(days < 1){
                                $(this).find('#countDown').css('color','red');
                                $(this).find('#countDown pre:nth-of-type(1)').css('display','none');
                        }
                        if(seconds < 10){ $(this).find("#countDown").append("&nbsp;"); };
                        if(minutes < 60){ interval = 1000; };
                }
                i++;
        });
        setTimeout(countdownProcedure,interval);
};
```

Comment: `setTimeout` takes *milliseconds*, not seconds.

Comment: I don't know what's in each of your table rows but you don't appear to ever change the value of #sqbTimestamp.text so it remains the same each iteration. I dont fully understand what its doing - can you post more code or a Fiddle?

Comment: Well it looks like you don't update the text of #sqbTimestamp, so log(tsInt - 3) will always be the same.

Comment: "*At the end of the function I want it to remove the interval timer from the ammount of seconds in the span tag*" - I don't see that anywhere?

Comment: I have put a version on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RpUv3/2/. Feedback would be appreciated - as you can see the function keeps running but the number of seconds remains the same.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RpUv3/2/

Comment: Still the same problem. Looks like a typo: `$(this).find("#sqlTimestamp").text(tsInt - 3);` should read `$(this).find("#sqbTimestamp").text(tsInt - 3);`. I've changed it in [this cloned fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RpUv3/3/)

Answer (score 0):

This `$(this).find("#sqbTimestamp").html(tsInt + 1);` code snippet change amount of seconds in span container.

```
//Run countdown proecudure
countdownProcedure();

var runNo = 0;
function countdownProcedure(){
        var interval = 10000;
        var i = 0;
        var seconds = null;
        runNo++;
        $(".rfqTbl tr").each(function(){
                if(i > 0){
                        seconds = $(this).find("#sqbTimestamp").text();
                        var tsInt = parseInt($(this).find("#sqbTimestamp").text());
                        $(this).find("#sqbTimestamp").html(tsInt + 1);

                        var days = Math.floor(seconds / (60*60*24));
                        seconds -= days * 60 * 60 * 24;
                        var hours = Math.floor(seconds / (60*60));
                        seconds -= hours * 60 * 60;
                        var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
                        seconds -= minutes * 60;

                        $(this).find("#sqlTimestamp").text(tsInt - 3);
                        console.log(tsInt - 3);

                        if(days < 1){ days=""; }
                    $(this).find("#countDown").html(days + "<pre> Days</pre> " + hours + "<pre>:</pre>" + minutes + "<pre>:</pre>" + seconds + "<pre>Run Number: " + runNo + "</pre>");

                        if(days > 1){
                                $(this).find("#countDown").css({
                                        'color':'#2A7F15',
                                        'font-weight':'bold'
                                });
                        };
                        if(days < 1){
                                $(this).find('#countDown').css('color','red');
                                $(this).find('#countDown pre:nth-of-type(1)').css('display','none');
                        }
                        if(seconds < 10){ $(this).find("#countDown").append("&nbsp;"); };
                        if(minutes < 60){ interval = 1000; };
                }
                i++;
        });
        setTimeout(countdownProcedure,interval);
};
```

Comment: I have put a version on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RpUv3/2/. Feedback would be appreciated - as you can see the function keeps running but the number of seconds remains the same and does not decrease. Many thanks